# php, mysql, jquery, form element chain select

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, chaining

I'm having trouble with a chained (form element) select.
I can't seem to trigger with jquery the second select options to be populated with the select using $examplevar as a filter resulting from the option selected in the first dropdown list.

```
    <form name="vlan" action="" method="post"> 
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php
        $con_string= "host=example port=xxxx dbname=example user=example password=example";
        $db_con = pg_connect($con_string);
        $dev = pg_query($db_con, "SELECT DISTINCT \"Type\" FROM \"End_Devices\"");

                            echo "  
                            <a class=\"current_page_item\">Location NASID:</a>
                            <input type=\"text\" name=\"nasid\" />      
                            <br>
                            <a class=\"current_page_item\">Device Name:</a>
                            <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" />   
                            <br>
                            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"dvtype\"/>
                            <a class=\"current_page_item\">Device Type:</a> 
                            <select name=\"slType\" id=\"slType\">";

                            while ($device = pg_fetch_array($dev))
                            {
                                echo "<option id=\"" .$device['Type'].  "\">" .$device['Type']. "</option>";

                            }
                            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">

                                $(\"#slType\").chained(\"#slModel\");
                                $(\"#slType\").on(\"change\",function(){
                                    var slTypeID = $(this).val();
                                    $.post('inventoryTEST.php', {slTypeID:slTypeID}, function(data){
                                        $('#slModel').html(data);
                                    });
                                });

                            </script>";


                            echo "
                            </select>
                            <br>
                            <a class=\"current_page_item\">Device Model:</a>
                            <select  name=\"slModel\" id=\"slModel\" >";

                            if (isset($_POST['slTypeid']))
                            {
                                $selection = ($_POST(['slTypeid']));

                            }

                            $mod = pg_query($db_con, "SELECT \"Model\" FROM \"End_Devices\" WHERE \"Type\"=\"". $selection . "\"");
                            while ($model = pg_fetch_array($mod))
                            {
                                echo $_POST[type];
                                echo "<option id=\"" .$model['Model'].  "\">" .$model['Model']. "</option>";
                            }
                            echo "
                            </select>
                            <br>
                            <a class=\"current_page_item\">Physical Location:</a>
                            <input type=\"text\" name=\"location\" />
                            <br>
                            <a class=\"current_page_item\">Serial:</a>
                            <input type=\"text\" name=\"serial\" /> 
                            <br>
                            <a class=\"current_page_item\">IP Address:</a>
                            <input type=\"text\" name=\"ip\" />
                            <br>
                            <a class=\"current_page_item\">MAC:</a>
                            <input type=\"text\" name=\"mac\" />    
                            <br>
                            <a class=\"current_page_item\">SSID:</a>
                            <input type=\"text\" name=\"ssid\" />
                            <br>
                            <a class=\"current_page_item\">WLAN Area:</a>
                            <input type=\"text\" name=\"wlan\" />   
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        ";
                        ?>
                            <!--SUBMIT INPUT-->
                            <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Can anyone please advise on the code above?
I'm not able to trigger the on change event to populate the var which is used as filter on the sql query, to then populate the second chained dropdown.
thanks
Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solved it by using jquery and .ajax by passing the selected row content .change with post into external php where then i queried the db using it as a filter and while populating the 2nd combobox.